# Entity Framework Code First Relationship Issue

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

I'm struggling to get a specific code-first relationship working correctly. Basically I have the following classes:

```
public class Service
{
    public Guid ServiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ServicePackageService> ServicePackageServices { get; set; }
}

public class ServicePackageService
{
    public Guid ServicePackageServiceId { get; set; }

    public Guid ServiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }

    public Guid PackageServiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Service PackageService { get; set; }
}
```

The idea here is that a Service object can have multiple ServicePackageService objects. These PackageServiceObjects are related to a single Service, but then they have a PackageService property which is another relationship to the Service table.

In my configuration I'm using the following:

```
    public ServicePackageServiceConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Service);
        HasRequired(x => x.PackageService).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.PackageServiceId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

But the datatable that results is as follows:

```
   ServicePackageServiceId (PK)
   ServiceId (No foreign key appears on this column)
   PackageServiceId (FK)
   Service_ServiceId (FK)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to configure this relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all down to an error in the configuration.

The correct way to handle this relationship is to specify the following Service configuration:

```cs
HasMany(x => x.ServicePackageServices)
    .WithRequired(b => b.Service)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.ServiceId);
```

Along with a ServicePackageService configuration for the reverse relationship:

```cs
HasRequired(x => x.PackageService)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.PackageServiceId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```